# не могу подобрать элемент, по которому selenium нажмет кнопку

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

есть html:

```
<footer class="mt2">
          <button data-control-name="invite" aria-label="Пригласить участника *** установить контакт" id="ember687" class="full-width artdeco-button artdeco-button--1 artdeco-button--full artdeco-button--tertiary ember-view"><!---->
<span class="artdeco-button__text">
    Установить контакт
</span></button>
    </footer>
```

ни одним из возможных методов selenium не смог подобрать работающий вариант для нажатия на кнопку "Установить контакт"
пробовал эти методы:

```
find_element_by_id
find_element_by_name
find_element_by_xpath
find_element_by_link_text
find_element_by_partial_link_text
find_element_by_tag_name
find_element_by_class_name
find_element_by_css_selector
```

xpath постоянно меняется.
есть какие нибудь возможные рабочие варианты?

пробовал так:

```
find_element_by_link_text('Установить контакт')
find_element_by_partial_link_text('Установить')
find_element_by_class_name('full-width artdeco-button artdeco-button--1 artdeco-button--full artdeco-button--tertiary ember-view')
find_element_by_class_name('artdeco-button__text')
```

Comment: ну покажите кодом, как вы искали. Я сейчас вижу только сами методы поиска

Comment: добавил в вопрос @danilshik

Comment: Покажите Сайт и Traceback

Comment: @babyborn find_element_by_css_selector('footer.mt2 > button')

Comment: @danilshik работает как часы! а можно ссылку на доку где описано почему так? если есть конечно